# Foreground img sprites with compass and sass

Tags: sass, sprite, compass-sass

I know that compass provides a way to implement CSS sprites as background images using chunky png gem. However, the generated CSS makes use of CSS background image.

```
@import "images/icons/*.png"
@include all-icons-sprites
```

What if I wanted to use compass CSS sprites, but with an embedded image, instead of background images, and position the image sprite relative, in order to show part of it.

I could use compass to generate the sprite, but is there a mixin that could somehow generate the CSS for the class, so instead of background images it uses positioning?

Comment: If you try to do what I believe you're asking for, you're going to be disappointed.  If you're wanting to embed the sprite as `<img src="my/compass/sprite.png" />`, you'll have to use the `clip` property (which is a pain to deal with).  You could embed a transparent image and apply a background image to that, though.

Comment: Thanks, I think probably go with your solution ( with the transparent image) , and a span element wrapping the image with the background applied on it, since the clip property is not supported in IE7. That way I keep the best of both ( SASS and semantics of the alt attr). at least this how I see it.

Comment: It's a pity this question doesn't have a resolving answer. Using img instead of bg is preferable because img's get printed, and because bg's turn black in high-contrast accessibility mode. 
It is possible to use img's as sprites by giving the image an _absolute_ position relative to its container.